# Как отсортировать массив объектов по дате в MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Есть коллекция со следующей схемой:

```
var project = new Schema({
head:{
    head_task: String,
    userID: String
},
access_users: {
    type : Array ,
    "default" : []},
context_task: [{
            from_name: String,
            status: Boolean,
            task: String,
            created_task: {
                type: Date,
                default: Date.now()
             }
        }],
created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }});
```

Подскажите, как получить документ с сортировкой по полю context_task.created_task по убыванию. На сколько понимаю нужно использовать аггрегирование, след запрос `db.tasks.aggregate({$match :{"_id":ObjectId("590e2d7d4d4a5e0b647d0835")}}, {$sort: {"context_task.created_task": -1}}).pretty();` выводит документ в обычном порядке, сортировка не работает. Или же это все нужно делать уже на клиенте ?

Comment: Решение вопроса было найдено тут - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44285429/how-sort-array-of-objects-in-collection-mongodb?noredirect=1#comment75580540_44285429

Answer (score 0):

```
project.find().sort({"_id": 1}).exec(function(err,Result){

})
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Это не совсем то что нужно, в вашем ответе сортировка произойдет по главному _id документа.